# CSS Scale an Iframe depending on something in it

Tags: javascript

I have two different kinds of websites that can dynamically be added into an iframe. I have no influence on their source code.

One of them looks fine at normal scale. The other is too big and needs to be scaled to 0.75.

Unfortunately I do not know how I could distinguish them with Javascript (PHP is not an option because the site needs to be run locally in the browser too).

It is the source code of two or more devices that can be added to the local Wifi and get their own kinda random URL. 192.168.101.122 or 192.168.101.39 for example.

I thought about getting the title tag of each, but since they are not in the same domain I dont think I can access that with javascript, can I?

How could I distinguish them with Javascript so that I can scale down the ones that are too big?

Comment: You can not access inside a cross domain iframe to change any scaling  due to *"same origin policy"*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested this method : get the src of the site, load it in a string thanks to an http request and then read the result (here )

```
           <iframe width="500" src="http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/"></iframe>

        var src = $("iframe").attr("src");

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: src,
            success: function (response) {
                var n = response.search("<title>");
                if (n != -1) {
                    var title = response.substr(n + 7, 100);
                    n = title.search("</title>");
                    if (n != -1) {
                        var title = title.substr(0, n);
                        alert(title);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            } // end error
        }); // end ajax

    });
```

The result is : "Quick Start Guide - Leaflet - a JavaScript library for interactive maps"

Know that it is the big site change the zoom level :

$("iframe").css("zoom",0.75);

Comment: But I cannot distinguish them that way. Their URLS do not give away which is which. ( I did not downvote you btw)

Comment: so the deal is to be able to parse something specific inside the child element : the iframe ?

Comment: @PhilMaGeo shoot first ask later?

Comment: Yes I think so, unless there is a different approach that allows me to distinguish their content.

Comment: Jquery says: "The .contents() method can also be used to get the content document of an iframe, if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page." They are not on the same domain though.

Comment: are your sites in http or https ?

Comment: You may use an http request as i demonstrated in my answer

Comment: shoot twice killed the bear

Comment: Rather unpleasant to work 45 mn to help on lunch time and nothings happens : neither crap nor good

Comment: Sorry, I was busy. I havent had the time to test your approach yet. I will accept it/upvote it for now and check it later. Thank you for your input!

Comment: OK i'm a bit busy myself and tired. sorry for the complaining. Keep me informed as your question is of great interest